# creating folder using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, google-chrome-extension, directory

my question is simple yet can't find an answer !
How to make  my chrome extension create a folder on the PC ?

farther more , my extension download files, mainly word doc. , I want my extension to check if there is a folder with specific name(on the desktop for example ) if not ; create a new one named  and save files inside of it.

Comment: Extensions can't do that directly but you can simply specify the path in chrome.downloads.download e.g. `filename: 'foo/bar.txt'`

Comment: the thing is that , my extension is the one who is generating the files using html elements to generate them , then creates a link and click it and then remove it